# Reloading a page using jQuery while retaining some data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Are there any clever ways of resetting a page back to it's original state (basically a reload) without having the screen physically look like it resets.

Basically i have a bunch of ajax requests, variables and content that i want wiped when a user clicks 'new' (currently i'm using just using `location.reload();` ) but want a more graceful way of doing it.

I'm really wanting to refresh it without the screen going white for a split second and also want to retain a single modal popup i have which is open when the user clicks 'new'.

So the user clicks the 'new' button, a popup appears taking a parameter, the site refreshes and the parameter is passed to an Ajax request kicking off the start process.

If anyone could point me in the direction of what to even look for it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to have the content you want to reload inside a container i.e.:

```
<div id="container"> page content </div>
```

Then when you have successfully got new data from the ajax call you can empty the container with:

```
$("#container").empty();
```

and repopulate it with

```
$("#container").append(newcontent);
```

Answer (score 2):

"Are there any clever ways of resetting a page back to it's original state (basically a reload) without having the screen physically look like it resets."

You can't refresh the website without making it look like it refreshed, the browser needs time to display the content.

You can, however, use jQuery [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load some standard markup into your site to make it appear as it did when it was initialized, the browser won't refresh, just like making an AJAX call doesn't require the website to refresh.

I'm, however, unable to see why you want the website to refresh if only to make an AJAX call.

Comment: it was really to reset all the variables, i thought there may be a command which offered a global reset of all variables.  But i'll look into .load thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to put data in [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), or in the url after a [`#`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) before the reload. But your options for having it look like it isn't refreshing are pretty limited outside of jQuery `.load` or an XHR request (which is what the jQuery load does)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.load` to request and replace a portion of your page, e.g. a container element.

For example, calling the following on index.html would effectively "reset" the #container element:

```
$("#container").load("index.html #container");
```

See "Loading Page Fragments" on the [docs for $.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

As for resetting variables and cancelling any pending ajax requests - you could perhaps write a reset() function to do all that for you.